# what is playback speed in ubuntu's default movie player

Tags: video-player

I have a movie which has been recorded by a digital cam at 1000 fps. When I play it in Ubuntu's default movie player (Video 3.10.1) I am not quite sure at what frame per second rate it gets played since the duration of what gets played is far longer than what I have recorded, say, minutes for a few second of recorded movie.

Comment: Might be a bug. Tried another player?

Answer (score 0):

Your computer running Ubuntu might not be able to playback at 1000fps, so it tries to playback as fast as possible which will be variable depending on the varying complexity of the video.